# sublime text 3 high memory usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimetext

recently noticed high memory usage of Sublime Text 3 (3.2.2 Build 3211) and it became slower
I have only 2 files opened, they are python files with 100-300 lines of code

I see following memory usage, and it is very slow, sometimes I even can't type.

[image]

Is there any way for to solve it?

---

on more observation, it starts eating a lot of memory only in case when I open file from the solder which contains a lot of other files

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could imagine such ram usage is if you have a file open from an extremely large git repo with an extremely high number of un-tracked or modified files.

Creating a list of every file and folder uses memory to store each file path in memory, and then it will start working on indexing the contents of all of those files, which will add to memory usage also

#### Solution 1:

Revert to a freshly installed state

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/revert.html

#### Solution 2:

Install sublime text alternatives

https://beebom.com/sublime-text-alternatives/

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it. By disabling git integrations reduced my RAM usage from 10gb to 45mb. Everytime it was tracking the git files of the whole sub-folders. Which hogged my RAM as soon as sublime was started.

Go to Preferences -> Settings and set false to "show_git_status" flag, also "show_git_status_in_status_bar" flag.

```
"show_git_status_in_status_bar": false,
"show_git_status": false,
```

Ref: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/git_integration.html#settings

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! RAM went down from 1.5GB to around 400MB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved by uninstalling the "Anaconda" plugin. If you are using that plugin, try uninstalling it and Sublime will go back to normal speed.